# Apply Ito's Formula to a Process

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations

I have the process,

$$\gamma_t = \exp\{\int_0^t \sigma_s dW_s-\frac{1}{2} \int_0^t \sigma_s^2 ds\}$$

And I wish to apply Ito's formula. My course provides the proof:

Denote the exponent in $\gamma_t$ by $X_t$. Then by Ito's formula,

$$d\gamma_t = \gamma_t dX_t + \frac{1}{2}\gamma_t(dX_t)^2 = \gamma_t (\sigma_tdW_t - \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 dt) + \frac{1}{2} \gamma_t \sigma^2 dt = \gamma_t\sigma_tdW_t$$

I am unsure as to why we have an extra $\sigma$ in the second term since just, $(dX_t)^2=dt$ in the second term.

Apologies if I have made some simple mistake

Comment: Are you sure you do not want integrals to appear in the exponent of the exponential? Otherwise how do you interpret this term? Then everything should be clear hopefully

Comment: Yes that was a mistake, I have made an edit. Now I am only unsure about the sigma in second term

Comment: We have $(dX_t)^2=(\sigma_t dW_t)^2=\sigma_t^2 dt$. This can be seen with the Ito-formula for $f(x)=x^2$.

Comment: Informally, $(dX_t)^2=(σ_t\,dW_t)^2=σ_t^2\,dt$. The other terms in the binomial expansion of $(dX_t)^2$ are too small to play a role.

Comment: Okay, I see. So it is only the case that $(dW_t)^2=dt$ for a Wiener process $W$?

Comment: Imagine $\sigma_t=2$ for all $t$. Then $\int_0^\cdot \sigma_t dW_t$ would behave like a Brownian motion that is "fluctuating twice as fast". So you would also expect its quadratic variaction to be larger than the one of a usual Brownian motion.